# Javascript - Add users ip address to form textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, forms

The script below collects the users external IP and writes it to the page, I want to be able to put this in to a `form` `textbox` and write the value to a database. everything I have tried results in a `null` value.

```
<!-- START: Here's the IP stuff -->
<script type="application/javascript">
function getIP(json) {

document.write(json.ip)

}
</script>

<script type="application/javascript" src="https://api.ipify.org?format=jsonp&callback=getIP"></script>
 <!-- END: IP Stuff -->



<form>
<input type="text" id="ipadderss">
</form>
```

Comment: So what have you tried???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Isn't this what you're trying to do? Using pure javascript you can change the input value with `document.getElementById("ipaddress").value = json.ip;`. Also moved the form to the top.

```html
<form>
    <input type="text" id="ipaddress">
</form>
<!-- START: Here's the IP stuff -->
<script type="application/javascript">
function getIP(json) {
    document.getElementById("ipaddress").value = json.ip;
}
</script>

<script type="application/javascript" src="https://api.ipify.org?format=jsonp&callback=getIP"></script>
 <!-- END: IP Stuff -->
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, I'd wasted an hour this morning looking at this. every time I added document.getElementById the value returned null. thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<form>
    <input type="text" id="ipAddress">
</form>
<script type="application/javascript">
function getIP(json) {
    document.getElementById("ipAddress").value = json.ip;
}
</script>
<script type="application/javascript" src="https://api.ipify.org?format=jsonp&callback=getIP"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<form>
    <input type="text" id="ipadderss"/>
</form>
<script>
     function getIP(json) {
       jQuery("#ipadderss").val(json.ip);
     }
</script>
<script type="application/javascript" src="https://api.ipify.org?format=jsonp&callback=getIP"></script>
```

See [JSfiddle](https://fiddle.jshell.net/snmu3jzh/).